Given $d(\vec{x},A):=\text{inf}\{\lVert\vec{x}-\vec{y}\rVert:\vec{y}\in A\}$, show that $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\overline{A}$
Let $A\subset \Bbb R^n$ and $\vec{x}\in \Bbb R^n$. Now, remember  that the distance between $\vec{x}$ and $A$ is given by: $$d(\vec{x},A):=\text{inf}\{\lVert\vec{x}-\vec{y}\rVert:\vec{y}\in 
A\}$$
Denote $f(\vec{x}) = d(\vec{x},A)$. Show that $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\overline{A}$
So, let's show that $f^{-1}(\{0\})\subseteq \overline{A}$ and $\overline{A}\subseteq f^{-1}(\{0\})$
Let $\vec{x}_0\in f^{-1}(\{0\})$, then $d(\vec{x}_0,A)=0$. Now observe that if $\partial A\nsubseteq A$, then there exists $\vec{y}\in A$ such that $\lVert\vec{x}_0-\vec{y}\rVert\ge d(\vec{x}_0,A)=0$, thus $\vec{x}_0\in \overline{A}$.
Let $\vec{x}\in \overline A$, then there exists $\{\vec{x}_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\subset A$  such that $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} \vec{x}_k=\vec{x}$, then $\lVert\vec{x}_k-\vec{x}\rVert\ge d(\vec{x},A)$.
Because $\lVert\vec{x}_k-\vec{x}\rVert\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$, so $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\lVert\vec{x}_k-\vec{x}\rVert=0\ge d(\vec{x},A)$, but $d(\vec{x},A)$ is always positive, so $d(\vec{x},A)=0$ and $\vec{x}\in f^{-1}(\{0\})$
We conclude that $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\overline A$
Does my proof works? If not, can you tell me please? Thanks.

What is the function $f$ in your post ?

It'll be $d(\vec{x},A)$

The second half is correct. The first half doesn’t make much sense to me.

Note that $d(x, A)=0$ iff for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $y\in A$ such that $d(x,y)<\varepsilon$, which is the same to say that every $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ at some point $y$.

Added $f$ explicitly to reduce confusion.

Your proof for $\text{Cl} A \subseteq f^{-1} (\{ 0 \})$ seems fine. The proof of the reverse inclusion is not correct: how does the existence of $y \in A$ such that $d (x_0, y) \ge 0$ imply that  $x_0 \in \text{Cl} A$?
An easier way to show this is to assume $x_0 \notin \text{Cl} A$, and to show that $f^{-1} (\{ 0 \})$ misses $x_0$, or what is the same, $d (x_0, A) = \inf\{ d (x_0, y) | y \in A \} > 0$. Well, if $x_0 \notin \text{Cl} A$, then there is some neighborhood $B_d (x_0, \varepsilon > 0)$ that misses $A$. This means $d (x_0, y) \ge \varepsilon$ for every $y \in A$. Thus, $\varepsilon > 0$ is a lower bound on the set $\{ d (x_0, y) | y \in A \}$, showing that $\inf\{ d (x_0, y) | y \in a \} > 0$, as desired.

For any metric space $(X,\rho)$ we have
$z\in  f^{-1}(\{0\})\iff f(z)=0\iff d(z,A)=0\iff \inf \{\rho (z,y) |y\in A\}=0\iff \forall \epsilon >0 \exists y\in A:\rho(z,y)<\epsilon\iff \forall \epsilon >0 \exists y\in A: y\in B_{\rho}(z,\epsilon)\iff \forall \epsilon >0: B_{\rho}(z,\epsilon)\cap A\neq \emptyset \iff z\in \overline A.$

As someone else said, your proof that $\bar{A}\subset f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is fine.
Your proof that $f^{-1}(\{0\})\subset \bar{A}$ is lacking though.
First, notice that if $A=\varnothing$, the result is clear.
Suppose now $A\neq\varnothing$ et let $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $d(x_0,A)=\inf\{\|x_0-y\|,y\in A\}=0$.
Then by definition of the infinimum, for every $n>0$ there exists $y_n\in A$ such that $\|x_0-y_n\|\le \frac{1}{n}$ (otherwise the infinimum would be $\ge \frac{1}{n}>0$). But the sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ converges to $x_0$. So $x_0 \in \bar{A}$.

For $\overline{A} \subseteq f^{-1}(\{0\})$ suppose $d(x,A)>0$. Take $2\varepsilon = d(x,A)$. Suffices to note that $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap A = \emptyset$. If not, then there exists $y\in A$ such that $2\|x-y\| < d(x,A)$, but that contradicts the assumption on $x$. Hence, $x$ cannot be in the closure of $A$.

Your argument becomes strange when you say

but $d(\vec{x},A)$ is always positive

What is $x$ here? Arbitrary? Why is it always positive?

Conversely, if $d(x,A)=0$ and $x$ is not a boundary point of $A$, then for some $\varepsilon >0$ we have either $B(x,\varepsilon )\cap A = \emptyset$ or $B(x,\varepsilon )\cap A^c = \emptyset$. In the first case however, we must have $\|x-y\|\geqslant \varepsilon$ for all $y\in A$, which cannot happen. So $B(x,\varepsilon)\setminus A =\emptyset$ must hold. Hence, $x\in A$.

Bu how does it shows that $\vec{x}_0\in f^{-1}({0})$?

To show $A\subseteq B$ it suffices to show $x\notin B$ implies $x\notin A$, yes? @Roma_Rayado
